# Laravel Socialite extend fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

Basically I want to get the user profile link from Linkedin. I use Laravel Socialite with [Socialite Providers](http://socialiteproviders.github.io/) to get the information from Linkedin.

When the user is redirected back to my site with success I've debugged the information:

```
User {#285 ▼
  +token: "XXX"
  +id: "XXX"
  +nickname: null
  +name: "XXX"
  +email: "XXX"
  +avatar: "XXX"
  +"user": array:4 [▶]
}
```

So i wanted to extend this information with "public-profile-url", this is a Basic Profile Field from Linkedin.

I tried to do something like this in the "myproject/vendor/socialiteproviders/linkedin/src/Provider.php":

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
   return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
       'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null,
       'name' => $user['formattedName'], 'email' => $user['emailAddress'],
       'avatar' => array_get($user, 'pictureUrl'),
       'link' => array_get($user, 'publicProfileUrl'),
   ]);
}
```

But then link will be "null".

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've currently fixed the problem.

In myproject/vendor/socialiteproviders/linkedin/src/Provider.php I've added the field 'public-profile-url' to the url:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function getUserByToken($token)
{
    $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get(
       'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,formatted-name,picture-url,email-address,public-profile-url)', [
        'headers' => [
            'Accept-Language' => 'en-US',
            'x-li-format'     => 'json',
            'Authorization'   => 'Bearer '.$token,
        ],
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
}
```

When you do this you can access the field 'publicProfileUrl' in the user array, example:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
{
    return (new User())->setRaw($user)->map([
        'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => null,
        'name' => $user['formattedName'], 'email' => $user['emailAddress'],
        'avatar' => array_get($user, 'pictureUrl'),
        'profileUrl' => array_get($user, 'publicProfileUrl'),
    ]);
}
```

Hopefully somebody will find this useful.

**Notice**
This is in the vendor directory! This code can be thrown away whenever you do an (composer) update on your project.

Comment: I followed your solution, but didn't want to lose my edits on each `composer update`. So I copied the socialiteproviders folder into a top-level `packages` folder that I use for my own (non-composer) packages. Then simply delete it from the `require` block in composer.json, and add two routes to the autoload/psr-4 like this: `"SocialiteProviders\\LinkedIn\\": "packages/socialiteproviders/linkedin/src",` and `"SocialiteProviders\\Manager\\": "packages/socialiteproviders/manager/src"`. Now run a composer update and everything should work just fine.